# linq to sql to get single value

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, distinct

I'm looking for a concise one line method to get a single value from a `DataTable` using lambda using `VB.Net`

This code works

```
OPT_UDLY = (From X In DATA.OPTIONs
                    Where X.CONTRACT = CTC
                    Select X.UDLY).Single()
```

but I'd like to get the value in one line like this (which doesn't work)

```
OPT_UDLY = DATA.Where(function(t) t.contract.Equals(CTC)).Distinct()
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
OPT_UDLY = Data.OPTIONs.Where(Function(t) t.CONTRACT = CTC).Select(Function(x) x.UDLY).Single()
```

1. Since you use `Data.OPTIONs` in the multiple LINQ lines, it should be consistently used for single line too.
2. Also, since you only need the `UDLY` element, use further `Select` `LINQ` expression in single line style, like what you did in your multiple lines.
3. And lastly, use `Single` to return the matching value if there is only one match, like what you already did.

Comment: @Zeus glad to know that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the line feeds:

`OPT_UDLY = (From X In DATA.OPTIONs Where X.CONTRACT = CTC Select X.UDLY).Single()`

It's shorter and more readable than the lambda equivalent:

`OPT_UDLY = Data.OPTIONs.Where(Function(t) t.CONTRACT = CTC).Select(Function(x) x.UDLY).Single()`